# How do i manage my battery more efficiently?

Tags: laptop, battery

My computer:

> Dell XPS | i7-2630QM 2.2-2.9 GHz | 4GB DDR3 1333Mhz | 2 GB Nvidia Optimus

And, is there a way to use Intel's Turboboost?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well there's a known bug with the kernel but you can try this solution!

Open a terminal with `ctrl+alt+T` and put these commands one by one, copy one line at a time.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:artfwo/ppa

sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get install indicator-cpufreq
```

When you reset your pc will have an icon on the tray. Select the conservative plan for your cpu.

Comment: is there any method to use intel's turboboost in linux ?